# How many times can a user change the accepted answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Many times a user tends to change the accepted answer based on newer and 
briefer answers. How many times can a user change the accepted answer?
Is there any limit?

Comment: The limit is the mouse-button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no limit. The accepted answer can be changed as many times as the user wishes.

This is by-design. If a better answer comes in later, we want people to be able to accept that one instead. It also works as an encouragement for users to answer "old" questions if they have something more to contribute. The Stack Exchange sites are not a discussion forum; there is no such thing as an "old thread", you won't be given hostile looks of derision for "bumping" an old question, or other silliness.

Comment: So the who had answered correctly at the point the user wanted will loose his points which he had gained because someone published a better answer.

Comment: Yes. When your answer is accepted, you gain +15 reputation. If your answer is unaccepted, you lose -15 reputation. It's not a big deal. The focus is not on reputation, it's on getting good answers. If a better answer comes along, that's the better answer and we want it to be on top.

Comment: You made the right point. Though I agree with a half heart. Thank you.

Comment: @kat - then you can half up vote or half accept this answer ;)

Comment: I did both fully. :)

Comment: however, I believe there are some time locks on how often you can do this to prevent absurdity. I'd have to check.

Comment: There currently is no limit on changing accepted answers, but our data shows this lack of throttling is not an issue.